# Maya - Rotate an object around it's pivot point by snapping a vertex to another object's point

Tags: maya

The title of the question maybe a bit confusing, so I'll try to make it clear. I have the object (A - finger) and I want to align rotation of another object (B - nail)  to a specific edge on the surface of the object A. So I set the pivot point of the object B to it's approximate central vertex and afterwards snapped the whole object B to vertex of the object A, but I don't know how rotate the object B like on the image below.

I know how to accomplish that in Blender, but not in Maya.

[image]